# Using value from macro variable to create an scheduled pipeline-job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I wonder if it's possible in azure devOps to get the following work:

1. The user `run` a pipeline and enter 3 Macro-Variables: `startDate, startTime, duration`.
2. Based on the macro-variables, a pipeline-job should be scheduled to do something (e.g. a pipeline which set webpage in maintenance mode.

Or is the better way to solve this, to immediately run a pipeline, which create a scheduled command (e.g. via `at` on linux-bash) that will be executed in the future?

Comment: You can schedule your pipeline runs using an API call. For example you could use task scheduler on windows and powershell, ansible or any other tool you prefer and you will only need to trigger the pipeline using an API call. Attaching an article how to trigger a build pipeline using the Azure devOps API. https://blog.geralexgr.com/cloud/trigger-azure-devops-build-pipelines-using-rest-api

Comment: I need to start the pipeline from devOps GUI in this case. (requirement that was given to me)